# Concurrent blocking Tasks in a BackgroundWorker

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm using a [StaTaskScheduler](https://web.archive.org/web/20160724072136/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/pfxteam/archive/2010/04/07/9990421.aspx) (TPL extension) to open some web browser windows simultaneously and navigate to different sites (using [WatiN](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WatiN/), but it might as well just be a `WebBrowser`).

In my example below I'm running 5 concurrent browsers. Works fine, but it locked the UI thread, so I wrapped my tasks in a `BackgroundWorker`. Seems like it does the job, but is it the correct way of handling the issue? Do I need to dispose the worker once I'm done? And finally, is `lock (ret)` the correct way of keeping `ret` thread safe?

```
StaTaskScheduler sta = new StaTaskScheduler(5);
BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();

bw.DoWork += (s, ea) =>
{
    List<string> ret = new List<string>();

    lock (ret)

    Task.WaitAll(Util.GetList().Select(row => Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {

        IEnumerable<string> result = DoUiLockingWork(row.Item1, row.Item2);
        ret.AddRange(result);

    }, CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, sta)).ToArray());

    ea.Result = ret;
};

bw.RunWorkerCompleted += (s, ea) =>
{
    List<string> result = ea.Result as List<string>;

    if (result != null) 
        Debug.WriteLine(result.Count);
};

bw.RunWorkerAsync();
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would go with Task-based method (if you're using .Net 4.5) instead of the `BackgroundWorker`. That will sort out most of your problems.

Something in the vicinities of

```
async Task<List<T>> yourJobAsync(...)
{
    var results = await Task.Run ( () =>
    {
        //your job.
        return jobResults
    });
    return  yourJobAsyncResults
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I actually changed the approach to your suggestion once I noticed that backgroundworkers were obselete. Can this return a result from all the nested tasks, without using `lock`?

Comment: Yes it can. You must have found out the answer by now but in general `Task<T> would return a `T`. If you use `IEnumrable<T>` instead of the `List` you should be able to use `Yield()` to return the task result. Check this Microsoft post about `yield return` and the example. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2008/07/23/8768673.aspx

Answer (score 4):

I would make your lock a little more tight:

```
lock (ret)
{
    ret.AddRange(result);
}
```

But otherwise, looks like an all right implementation.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I also replaced the backgroundworker implementation with a pure `Task` solution.